# shared libraries (dlopen) and thread-safety of library static pointers

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

When I load a shared library dynamically, for example with `dlopen` on linux, do I have to worry about the visibility of the loaded library between processors, or will it be automatically fenced/ensured safe?

For example, say I have this function in the loaded library:

```
char const * get_string()
{  return "literal"; }
```

In the main program using such a string-literal pointer is safe between multiple threads as they are all guaranteed to see its initial value. However, I'm wondering how the rules of "initial values" really apply to a loaded library (as the standard doesn't deal much with it.

Say that I load the library, then immediately call the `get_string` function. I pass the pointer to another thread via a non-memory sequenced atomic (relaxed in C++11 parlance). Can the other thread use this pointer safely without having to issue any load fence or other syncronization instruction?

My assumption is that it is safe. Perhaps because the new library will be loaded into new pages the other core cannot have them loaded yet, and thus cannot have old visibility on them?

I would like some kind of authorative reference as part of the answer if possible. Or a technical description of how it is made thread-safe by default. Or of course a refutation if it isn't thread-safe on its own.

Comment: @DeadMG, this is still C/C++ related. I'm using a C string literal construct because it has specific lifetime gaurantees. Furthermore, the specific language compiler/linker is definitely involved in resolving this, and from that point of view I'm interested in a C or C++ language toolchain.

Comment: It has no more lifetime guarantee than any other static data in any other native code library. And the language compiler/linker has nothing to say about `dlopen`- it's an OS function that acts the same on every native code library, regardless of source language. Oh, and C and C++ are vastly different languages and whether you want one or the other is a pretty crucial thing to know before you ask the question.

Comment: `dlopen` is of course not an OS function but part of glibc on Linux. The results of dlopen are only usuable in a language that supports raw pointer access, thus C and C++ primarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll expand on what Basile said. I followed up with glibc and found out dlopen there does in deed use mmap. All guarantees of memory visibility are assumed from the mmap system call, dlopen itself doesn't make any additional guarantees.

Users of mmap generally assume that it will map memory correctly across all processors at the point of its return such that visibility is not a concern. This does not appear to be an explicit guarantee, but the OS would probably be unusable without such a guarantee. There is also no known system where this doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is : will `dlopen()` load all my lib code properly before returning ? Yes it will. **Otherwise you'd have the problem with only a single thread.** It would be very difficult to handle if you had to sleep before dlopen completes asynchronously. It will also perform various checks and initialize what needs to be **before** you have a chance to get the function pointer you are looking for. That means that if you get that pointer, everything is here, you can use directly in any thread.

Now of course, you need to pass that pointer with the usual thread safety, but I assume you know how.

Please be aware that static initialization and modules don't play well together (see all the other questions on SO about that subject).

Your comment on cores is strange. Cores don't load memory. They prefetch it in their cache, but that's not a problem, just a bit slow.

Comment: No, I am specifically concerened about the visibility to other processors.

Comment: It is visible to other cores (running other threads of the same process), because `mmap` is modifying the address space of all threads inside a process (by definition of "process"), and because cores have hardware assisted cache coherence. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence

Comment: @Basile, I understand cache coherence, but is dlopen guaranteed to use mmap, and is it guaranteed to not reuse existing address space? Also, the CPU won't lock other threads during the load (or will it?), so I'm not clear on how the other thread will be forced to sync.  Again, I understand most likely it is safe, I'm just looking for the specs/docs which state this (I hate assuming anything)

Comment: I have no idea of what `dlopen` *guarantees*, but all the implementations I know of it are doing `mmap` (and when you think about it, they need to modify the address space, and `mmap` is the best way to do that, unless you have specific other system calls, like the old Linux deprecated `uselib(2)` syscall). And other threads do not have to *sync* explicitly (the kernel is doing that work). See Posix http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html

Comment: As an aside, the JVM uses the synchronyzing properties of `mprotect()` for asymmetric barriers/synchronization: do a dummy read from a special memory page without any barrier/synchronization; when the write side wants to force visibility in the read side, `mprotect()` the page until all threads reach a quiescent state (I think either a safepoint or outside JITted code).