# Injecting dynamic lib into a thread

Tags: rust

I am using the [libloading](https://crates.io/crates/libloading) crate to load a dynamic library that I need to use in multiple threads.

```
let lib = Library::new("lib.dylib").unwrap();
```

Do I load the library on each thread, or is there a way to inject/share the library into a thread when the thread is started?

Comment: https://docs.rs/libloading/0.5.2/libloading/struct.Library.html#impl-Send You can share the Library instance around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shared libraries are [loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9553380/257568) into a *process*. It shouldn't matter what *thread* you've used to load the library, the code should equally be available to all the threads once the library has been loaded. This is because the POSIX threads share the same memory space, namely the memory space of the *process*.

When a CPU jumps to a memory address belonging to a loaded library, the memory is already there, mapped by the operating system into the process memory space. Threads has no influence whatsoever on the availability of the said memory address.

Keep in mind though, that according to the [library documentation](https://docs.rs/libloading/0.5.2/libloading/struct.Library.html#thread-safety) you might want to avoid calling `Library::new` from multiple threads simultaneously.